# How to access nested field of an array element inside a set operation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to access a `nested field` of an array element in `$set` operation.
I have a document like,

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  automated: [
      {
          price: 80.0,
          currency: 'USD',
          ...otherData
      },
      {
          price: 90.0,
          currency: 'INR',
          ...otherData
      },
      {
          price: 120,
          currency: 'USD',
          ...otherData
      }
  ]
}
```

I want to create a `finalData` obj which takes some values from first element of the array.

So I tried,

```
mongodb.aggregate([
    {"$set": {
        "finalData" : {
            "price": "$automated.0.price",       // 0th index
            "currency": "$automated.0.currency"
        }
    }}
])
```

But this is not working and the result is,

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  finalData: {
    price: [],
    currency: []
  },
  ...otherData
}
```

I could not find any similar examples.
Does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

Found a [similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454068/find-a-nested-object-field-inside-an-array-in-mongodb-aggregate)
The proposed solution works,

```
mongodb.aggregate([
    {"$set": {
        "finalData" : {
            "price": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$automated.0.price", 0]       // index used here
            },
            "currency": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$automated.0.currency", 0]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

But this doesn't feel intuitive and would be happy to know if there are any alternatives to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$automated.0.price"` syntax is used for find/update operations but not in aggregation pipeline.

Simply use

```
mongodb.aggregate([
    {"$set": {
        "finalData" : {$first: "$automated"}
    }}
])
```

or

```
mongodb.aggregate([
    {"$set": {
        "finalData" : {
           price: {$first: "$automated.price"}, 
           currency: {$first: "$automated.currency"}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thought about the fist one, but doesn't apply to my use case. The second one throws an error `any argument for $first must be an array, but it is object`. I also tried to enclose it in an array, but to no avail.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Ah! Thanks. This works